# dotnet web service & tests: removal of base impossible since base already used

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, web-services

I created in visual studio an ASP.NET web project, in which I added an asmx file in order to transform it to a webservice. It worked.
I created also a model project which uses entity framework to generate a database, a SQL server express instance(not the local database).
finally, I created a test project which contains all my unit tests.

the webservice's purpose is to read the database and answer to requests by providing the caller with the content of the database.

In order to clear the database and allow repeatable tests, I need to clean the database; in order to do that, I created a class inheriting from DropCreateDatabaseAlways.

The solution can be built, but when I run the test, I a advised that the database Market can't be deleted since it is already used. Althought I closed SqlServer Management Studio, the problem remains.
I think (thanks to confirm) the problem comes from the same database connection string used in the webservice, in the model project, and in the test project. I can be open multiple times and generates this error.

How to clear properly the database?(not SQL statements please).

Here are some files:

first, the MarketContext file:

```
namespace Model.EntityFrameworkHelperClasses
{
    public class MarketContext : DbContext
    {
        //public MarketContext() : base("name=sqlserver") { }
        public MarketContext(DbConnection conn) : base(conn,false) { }


        public virtual DbSet<Magasin> Magasins { set; get; }

        public virtual DbSet<ProduitMagasin> ProduitsMagasin { set; get; }

        public virtual DbSet<Rayon> Rayons { set; get; }




    }
}
```

The web service's method which provides the database' content to its caller:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Magasin> getMagasins()
    {
        //récupération en base
        DbSet<Magasin> dbMagasins = null;
        List<Magasin> magasins = new List<Magasin>();

        var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-5J321S5\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;;Initial Catalog=Market;Pooling=false");
        conn.Open();

        using (var ctx2 = new MarketContext(conn))
        {
            dbMagasins = ctx2.Magasins;
            foreach (var mg in dbMagasins)
            {
                magasins.Add(mg);
            }
        }

        return magasins;
    }
```

next, a part of web.config in the webservice' project:

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="sqlserver" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-5J321S5\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;;Initial Catalog=Market;Pooling=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

the same part is included in the App.config file in the model project, and in the test project.

last, but not least, the test file in the Test project:

```
namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestsWebService
    {
        Market5.market Service5 = null;


        [TestInitialize]
        public void setUp()
        {
            //récupération du service
            Service5 = new Market5.market();

            //remplissage de la base

            var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-5J321S5\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;;Initial Catalog=Market;Pooling=false");
            conn.Open();
            using (var ctx = new MarketContext(conn))
            {
                //vidage tout d'abord
                new MyDataInitializer().InitializeDatabase(ctx);

                //puis remplissage
                var produitMagasin1 = new ProduitMagasin() { Nom = "Pommes", Quantite = 10 };
                var produitMagasin2 = new ProduitMagasin() { Nom = "Poires", Quantite = 5 };
                var rayon1 = new Rayon() { Nom = "fruits & légumes", Produits = new List<ProduitMagasin>() { produitMagasin1, produitMagasin2 } };
                var magasin1 = new Magasin() { Rayons = new List<Rayon>() { rayon1 } };

                ctx.Magasins.Add(magasin1);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

            }



        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void testBaseConstruiteDansSetUp()
        {


            //int result5 = service5.Multiply(2, 5);
            //Assert.AreEqual(10, result5);
            Market5.Magasin[] magasins = Service5.getMagasins();
            //Assert.AreEqual(1, sm.Magasins.Length);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, magasins[0].Rayons[0].Produits.Length);


        }




    }
}
```

and finally, the data initializer class:

```
namespace Model.EntityFrameworkHelperClasses
{
    public class MyDataInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MarketContext>
    {
        public override void InitializeDatabase(MarketContext context)
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction
                , string.Format("ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", context.Database.Connection.Database));

            base.InitializeDatabase(context);
        }

        protected override void Seed(MarketContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

        }




    }
}
```

The first question is : How to get rid of this error message?

thank you.

EDIT: I forgot to specify I published the webservice to IIS express, on windows 10.

Comment: This is all over the place. You ask about "clearing" a database. You also ask "How to get rid of this error message?". What does "clearing" the database even mean? And what error message are you getting?

Comment: Yeah man. That /\. If you want help, you are going to need to REALLY simplify your question. I don't have the time or the desire to read all the code you posted here.

Comment: ok; in order to have tests using always the same sample database, in the SetUp method of the test project, I have to empty the database and then fill it with some prepared datas. I empty the database with a call to the InitializeDatabase method of the MyDataInitializer class,which is dedicated to this purpose. but when running the test, th

Comment: ... the IDE complains with an error saying

Comment: ... that the flush of the base Market is impossible since the database is already in use. but I don't know how to solde it. sql server management studio is closed.